# Struts2 web.xml file filter jar for web application issue

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, struts2

I am currently in the middle of trying to create a small web application using the Struts2 framework. (In eclipse)

I am currently trying to use a filter in the web.xml (in the WEB-INF folder) file to transfer control over to the struts.xml file (in the src folder). (This is what I saw in a tutorial).

The code I am using for the filter is as follows:

```
<filter> 
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

I don't think Tomcat is finding the class in the JAR files for the filter as I keep getting this following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.cleanup(InitOperations.java:114)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:60)
>   ...continues for quite a while.

I have the Jar files downloaded from the Struts webpage and the way I went about setting to the build path is as follows:

I right clicked on the project and went to properties

Went to the Java Build Path section and created a new library

Added all of the Jar files to that library and assigned it to this web application's build path

I then added this Jar library to the Deployment Assembly so that when it runs it gets deployed to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

As far as I know this should work, as it works in the tutorial I have followed! However, it is not working for me.

When I run my project and navigate through my PC to where the project is saved, if I look in the WEB-INF/lib folder, there is no Jar files in there whatsoever, could this be where the problem lies? Or is this normal?

Thank you for any help, It's much appreciated!

EDIT

Here are the jar files I am using:

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.2
commons-io-2.0.1
commons-logging-1.1.1
commons-logging-api-1.1
freemarker-2.3.19
javaassist-3.11.0.GA
ognl-3.0.6
struts2-core-2.3.8
xwork-core-2.3.8
commons-lang-2.4
```

SOLVED - Solved by completely restarting the project on a fresh build!
UPDATE - Also fixed old build by removing all jars and recreating the jar library, and reassigning it to the build path/Deplyment Assembly (Did this hundreds of times whilst trying to debug, though)

Then removed the old Tomcat server and assigned a new one.

Not entirely sure what fixed it, but it's all working, for now

Comment: Check your eclipse war packaging. Maybe the dependency jar is there when you compile, but not packaged into the final war

Comment: Please show the complete list of jars.

Comment: @Dave I tried it with adding every single jar that came with the Struts2 download, there's like 80 of them!

Comment: Well, you shouldn't do that, because plugins can change how struts works. In any case, it sounds like you're either mixing versions or missing a transitive dependency. In order to help further, you need to list the jars you're deploying. Consider only deploying the jars you need.

Comment: @Dave Okay, I have only included the jars that the tutorial suggests, and which work for that, but surprise surprise don't work for me! Here is the list though just incase it is of any use :

commons-fileupload-1.2.2
commons-io-2.0.1
commons-logging-1.1.1
commons-logging-api-1.1
freemarker-2.3.19
javaassist-3.11.0.GA
ognl-3.0.6
struts2-core-1.3.10
xwork-core-2.3.8
commons-lang-2.4

Comment: Put the jars in the question. You're mixing versions, though, IIRC. Consider using Maven or an equivalent to avoid issues like this. Also, is difficult to tell if the deployment is correct in Eclipse.

Comment: What is struts2-core-1.3.10? For later versions of Struts 2, the XWork version should match, too.

Comment: I have no idea how I managed that typo! xwork-core and struts2-core are the same version - very sorry about that, but well noticed!

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext  (...) it seems like a dependency of the xwork2 is missing, check if you're linking all your jars to your project in an appropiate way.

Comment: Yep, seems like a deployment issue.

Comment: Without sounding too much like a novice: how would I check that I'm linking all the jars to my project in an appropriate way? In Eclipse my struts jar library with the aforementioned jars, is apparently linked to the WEB-INF/lib folder through the Deployment Assembly section - although they do not appear in the lib folder when I navigate to the project location on my PC.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the **Markers view** there should be a **Classpath Dependency
Validator Message warning group**. If you expand that group you should
see some warnings similar to:

**Classpath entry ??? will not be exported or published**.
 **RuntimeClassNotFoundExceptions may result.**

Right click on these warnings
 and select **Quick Fix**. This allows you to
mark the **classpath entry** for inclusion in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: I've not managed to fix it this way, however there is a marker for each of my jar files, saying that it will not be exported or published and may cause a class not found exception at runtime. The only options I have on quick fix are to either; exclude the associated raw class path entry, or mark the associated classpath entry as a publish/export dependency - neither of which seem to make a difference!

Comment: Manually modifying the .classpath files by copy & pasting the added
attribute that controls this might be a little faster, but probably not
much better overall.